# Get JSON file from GET request from Infoblox

Tags: python, json, python-requests, dns, infoblox

Currently i've got this piece of code, it looks like I get a `RESPONSE_CODE 200` (so i know it works) from my URL but it does not return any data. I've read something about sending `DATA_FILE_FORMAT` with the request so the server knows it has to return `JSON` or `XML`, ...

Anybody got some advice?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import requests
import json

rest_url = 'url_to_infoblox_api/network?network=192.168.1.0/24'
r = requests.get(url=rest_url, auth=('infoblox_username', 'infoblox_password'), verify=False)

r_json = r.json()

print r.status_code //return code 200, so it works!

print json.dumps({
    "data" : r_json //but i get no data ...
})
```

Comment: You may want to print out `r.text` so see what it is.

Answer (score 0):

As the skyline75489 suggests - try printing r_json.text to see the raw json. Then use the key you want to find the values you are interested in. For example if you have an extensible attribute called WindowPane then the following would return the value of that attribute.

```
r_json['extattrs']['WindowPane']['value']
```